# How to use Getopt::Long method?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

How can I use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long) method if the input command execution is like this:

```
$ testcmd -option check  ARG1 ARG2 ARG3
```

or

```
$ testcmd  ARG1 ARG2 ARG3
```

Comment: That depends on what you want to have done with those options and flags.  The people who answer below are trying to make their best guess, but mind-reading is a difficult skill to master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Getopt::Long;

sub usage { "Usage: $0 [--option=VALUE] ARG1 ARG2 ARG3\n" }

my $option = "default";

GetOptions("option=s", \$option)
  or die usage;

die usage unless @ARGV == 3;

print "$0: option=$option: @ARGV\n";
```

`Getopt::Long` is quite flexible in what it will accept:

```
$ ./cmd
Usage: ./cmd [--option=VALUE] ARG1 ARG2 ARG3

$ ./cmd 1 2 3
./cmd: option=default: 1 2 3

$ ./cmd --option=foo 4 5 6
./cmd: option=foo: 4 5 6

$ ./cmd -option=bar 7 8 9
./cmd: option=bar: 7 8 9

$ ./cmd -option check a b c
./cmd: option=check: a b c
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the `pass_through` option. Documentation quoted below:

> #### `pass_through` (default: disabled)
>
> Options that are unknown, ambiguous or
>   supplied with an invalid option value
>   are passed through in @ARGV instead of
>   being flagged as errors. This makes it
>   possible to write wrapper scripts that
>   process only part of the user supplied
>   command line arguments, and pass the
>   remaining options to some other
>   program.
>
> If `require_order` is enabled, options
>   processing will terminate at the first
>   unrecognized option, or non-option,
>   whichever comes first. However, if
>   `permute` is enabled instead, results
>   can become confusing.

[DVK's posted an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002062/how-can-i-allow-undefined-options-when-parsing-args-with-getopt/3002214#3002214) of how to do this in another answer. I'd upvote his answer first if you find it useful.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that values starting with "-" need to be passed through

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Getopt::Long;

my $cla = GetOptions (  "one=s"         =>      \$one,
                        "two=s"         =>      \$two,
                        "three=s"       =>      \$three,
                        "help|h|?"      =>      \$help,
) or usage ();

if ($help) {
        usage ();
}

my $first = $one;
my $second = $two;
my $third = $three;

printf ("%-7s %-9s %-7s\n", $first, $second, $third);

sub usage {
        print "\n$0\t" . "[ -one <text> -two <text> -three <text> ]\n\n";
        exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some sort of explanation to your code so it can be more useful.