# Ignoring unrecognized options when parsing argv?

Tags: python, getopt

I'm writing a script that acts as a proxy for a plugin class's `run` method.

The script would be invoked like this:

```
> main.py -v --plugin=Foo --extra=bar -c
```

The result of this command would be the equivalent of:

```
plugin = my.module.Foo()
plugin.run(extra='bar', c=True)
```

Note that anything in front of `--plugin` is used internally by main.py and not passed to the plugin.  Anything after `--plugin` is ignored by main.py and instead passed directly to the plugin.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a `getopt`-like class that will allow me to parse `argv` **without** having to specify a list of allowed options.

I'd prefer not to have to rewrite `getopt` with one line commented out.  Are there any better options out there?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002062/how-can-i-allow-undefined-options-when-parsing-args-with-getopt, but for Python instead of Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that [`getopt` will stop parsing if it encounters `--`](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/getopt/#special-case):

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:16) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from getopt import getopt
>>>
>>> argv = ['-v', '--plugin=foo', '--', '--extra=bar', '-c']
>>> opts, extra = getopt(argv, 'v', 'plugin=')
>>>
>>> opts
[('-v', ''), ('--plugin', 'foo')]
>>>
>>> extra
['--extra=bar', '-c']
```

Note that the above `argv` is the equivalent of calling:

```
> main.py -v --plugin=Foo -- --extra=bar -c
```

I like this solution particularly since it gives the user a little extra flexibility in how he wants to order the parameters.

Comment: This is the getopt version of the `argparse` method I posted above.

Comment: Marking as the accepted answer, as this is the method I ultimately went with.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is in the `argparse` library, see http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar')
>>> parser.parse_known_args(['--foo', '--badger', 'BAR', 'spam'])
(Namespace(bar='BAR', foo=True), ['--badger', 'spam'])
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for. This gets the known (pre-specified) arguments, where what is desired is getting long options without having to specify what they are first.

Comment: Any options it doesn't recognize will end up in the list in the second position in the tuple -- above, `badger` and `spam` aren't pre-specified. This list can just be passed to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something silly and just generate a dictionary from which you can look up keys and the like to determine what to do with each item...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys 
options = dict()
for pair in map(lambda item: item.lstrip('-'), sys.argv[1:]):
    pair = pair.split('=')
    if len(pair) < 2:
        option, val = pair[0], True
    else:
        option, val = pair
    options[option] = val 
print options
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. I wrote a [modified getopt](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/aid/pycopia/getopt.py) that does exactly that. One limitition, however, is that short options must precede long options. That may be fixable.

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression to search for `'plugin=`, and if found, split the line and use getopt to parse each half.

Comment: you don't need regexp to search for a fixed string.